# If I install Centos 6.4 minimal, an I still download everything I need later?

Tags: centos6.4

I'm repurposing and old server, so I need 32bit Centos.  6.4 is current.  If I get the minimal, can I yum to get anything else I need?  Am I limited if I don't get the full DVD download?

I want to use it for, httpd, svn or git, python, php, maybe other languages, nfs, smb.  Very small group using it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have an internet connection (or a repo mirror in your local network), you can install everything later.